# Angularjs Directive - Isolated scope value is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am a newbie in angularjs. I am little confused about isolated scope in directives. I have the following code,

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<body ng-controller="componentsController">
    <div class="scope-one" data-param="a">
        <div class="scope-two" data-param="c"></div>
    </div>
    <!---->
</body>
</html>
```

**Script**

```
angular.module('components', [])
    .controller('componentsController', function($scope){
        $scope.a = {
                "b": 1
            };
        $scope.c = { 
                "d": 2
            };
    });

    angular.module('myApp', ['components'])
        .directive('scopeOne', function() {
            return {
                restrict: 'C',
               scope: {
                    a: "=param"
                },
                link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                    console.log('one', scope);
                }
            };
        })
        .directive('scopeTwo', function() {
            return {
                restrict: 'C',
                scope: {
                    c: "=param"
                },
                link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                    console.log('two', scope);
                }
            };
        })
```

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/jPtb3/23/

**Problem**
I have two directives `scope-one` and `scope-two` and I am using `scope-two` inside `scope-one`. For `scope-one`, the isolated scope is fine and proper whereas for `scope-two` the values is `undefined`. I am not getting the problem, am I doing something wrong? Both the isolated scope values are fine, when one directive is not in another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Scenario 1**: When `scope-two` is not inside `scope-one` both the directives are directly under the scope of the controller and everything works as expected.

**Scenario 2**: When `scope-two` is inside `scope-one` the former directive moves inside the scope of the latter and not directly under the scope of the controller.

In this situation you would need to use `$parent` to access the model `c` of the controller scope.

This works for me:

```
<div class="scope-one" data-param="a">
    <div class="scope-two" data-param="$parent.c"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome, you are a geek... Thanks a ton. But, which is a good way to do it. Previously you fixed it, by sending the scope with another `param` in `scope-one`. Which is a best way?

Comment: This one is quite natural and a lot more cleaner than the one I mentioned earlier. I would suggest this one.